# exec options : what is zeroth argument to command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
help exec
```

indicates this option to exec

```
-a name   pass NAME as the zeroth argument to COMMAND
```

What is Zeroth argument to the command ?

```
-l                place a dash in the zeroth argument to COMMAND
```

What does placing dash in zeroth argument mean ?

Comment: Thanks. How did I forget $0 from `basename $0`.

Comment: ( echo hello ; exec -l -a testps ps -o pid,ppid,cmd)

Comment: ( echo hello ; exec -a testps ps -o pid,ppid,cmd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the name used to invoke the script.

Running from the command line it can be changed by invoking the script through a link.

Comment: ( echo hello ; exec -a testps ps -o pid,ppid,cmd)

Comment: ( echo hello ; exec -l -a testps ps -o pid,ppid,cmd)

Answer (score 3):

As you've been told, the zeroth argument is what appears in `argv[0]`, conventionally the name of the program being executed.  However, 'conventionally' means that anything can appear there, and the `-a` option gives you a way to control what appears there.

```
$ (exec -a sharktank ps -t ttys003)
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
  574 ttys003    0:00.02 login -pf jleffler
  575 ttys003    0:00.07 -bash
 9507 ttys003    0:00.00 sharktank -t ttys003
$
```

The `-l` option adds a dash before the command name (zeroth argument).  This is a convention used by the `login` program to tell shells that they are 'login shells' and should process profiles or equivalent.

For example:

```
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
37617 ttys000    0:00.01 -bash
$ bash
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
37617 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
37672 ttys000    0:00.01 bash
$ exit
exit
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
37617 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
$
```

The dash indicates that the shell for process 37617 was the initial login shell for the terminal window.  This has been how Unix shells detected that they were login shells back to at least 7th Edition (Version 7) UNIX, though it was not necessarily clearly documented.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X compare:

```
(exec -a foo sh -c 'echo $0')
(exec -l -a foo sh -c 'echo $0')
(exec -l -a foo sh -c 'echo $0' arg0)
```